# Designing a language with Checked Exceptions

Tags: exception, language-design

I'm well aware of the whole argument over whether or not checked exceptions are a good idea and I fall on the side that they are...but that is not the point of this question. I'm in the process of designing a fairly simple compiled OOP language and I've decided to use checked exceptions basically as a way of returning errors without going down the C route of returning error codes.

I'm looking for some insight as to how I could improve on the Java model of checked exceptions to eliminate most of their bad aspects, perhaps a syntactic change or changing the actual functionality slightly. One of the main criticisms against checked exceptions is that lazy programmers are likely to swallow them and so errors would not appear.

Perhaps it could be optional to catch exceptions and therefore if one is not caught the program would crash? Or maybe there could be specific notation to denote that an exception is not being handled (like the C++ virtual function '= 0' notation)? Or I could even cause the program to crash if the exception handler is empty (though this might surprise programmers new to the language)?

How about the try...catch syntax, do you think there could be a more concise way of expressing that an exception is being caught? The language will use a garbage collector, much like Java, so is there any need for the finally clause? Finally, what other disadvantages are there to checked exceptions and what potential solutions (if any) exist?

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for? A model that suits you, personally? If so, then decide that for yourself. A model that suits others? Java actually handles some of the cases you bring up (via the `throws` clause, etc). And implementing "finally" has nothing to do with garbage collection, really, so ... Personally, I think you need to do a bit more research on your own. JMHO.

Comment: I expect this will get closed as subjective, since there's no "right answer" (I see someone's already voted that way). For this sort of question, I'd suggest marking it "community wiki", since that means "there's no one right answer, let's just collaborate on it".

Comment: I'm looking for a model that suits other people and I'm looking for suggestions rather than a subjective debate. As the language designer, I will of course make the final decision but I don't want to reinvent the problems of other languages.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear in my earlier comment. Recommend editing your question and ticking the "Community Wiki" tickbox (if you still can).

Comment: I've changed it to Community Wiki as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm well aware of the whole argument over whether or not checked exceptions are a good idea and I fall on the side that they are...

FWIW, I agree -- by and large, they're a Good Thing(tm). The bad habits of programmers around the use of a feature do not necessarily mean a feature is bad. In most cases, I think programmers don't understand that they can take a pass on the exception and buck it up the chain.

> Perhaps it could be optional to catch exceptions and therefore if one is not caught the program would crash?

Java has that feature (`RuntimeException` and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions).

> Or maybe there could be specific notation to denote that an exception is not being handled...

Java has that; the `throws` clause in the method declaration.

> How about the try...catch syntax, do you think there could be a more concise way of expressing that an exception is being caught?

Granted it can feel a bit clunky, but the goal is to factor exceptional conditions out of the mainline logic.

However, I do have a couple of suggestions for `try..catch`:

#### `catch..from`

This is something I've wanted in Java and related languages for a long time (really need to write this up properly and submit a JSR): `catch...from`.

Here's an example:

```
FileOutputStream    output;
Socket              socket;
InputStream         input;
byte[]              buffer;
int                 count;

// Not shown: Opening the input and output, allocating the buffer,
// getting the socket's input stream

try
{
    while (/* ... */)
    {
        count = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        output.write(buffer, 0, count);

        // ...
    }
}
catch (IOException ioe from input)
{
    // Handle the error reading the socket
}
catch (IOException ioe from output)
{
    // Handle the error writing to the file
}
```

As you can see, the goal here is to separate the unrelated error handling for socket read errors and file write errors. Very basic idea, but there are a lot of subtleties involved. For instance, exceptions thrown by other objects being used under-the-covers by the socket or file output stream instance need to be handled as though thrown by that instance (not that hard, just need to be sure instance information is in the stack trace).

This is something one *can* do with existing mechanisms and strict coding guidelines, but it's very difficult.

#### Multiple catch expressions in a single block

A'la the planned JDK7 enhancements.

#### Retry

Very, very much harder to provide than the above and also much easier for people to work around, so the value's a lot lower. But: Provide a "retry" semantic:

```
try
{
    // ...stuff here...

    if (condition)
    {
        foo.doSomething();
    }

    // ...stuff here...
}
catch (SomeException se)
{
    if (foo.takeRemedialAction() == Remedy.SUCCESS)
    {
        retry;
    }

    // ...handle exception normally...
}
```

Here, `doSomething` can fail in an exceptional way, but in a way that `takeRemedialAction` may be able to correct. This continues the theme of keeping the exceptional conditions out of the main line of logic. Naturally, `retry` takes execution back to the operation that failed, which may be deep in `doSomething` or some submethod it's called. You see what I mean about challenging.

This one is much easier for teams to do with existing mechanisms: Just make subroutine that's `doSomething` plus `takeRemedialAction` on exception, and put that call in the main line logic instead. So, this one's low on the list, but hey...

Comment: 10+ years on, I've *finally* gotten around to at least doing a blog post on `catch..from`: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/02/catchfrom.html Maybe I'll get to doing a JSR this year.

Comment: The problem with your retry thing is that there is no way to know where to retry from. The JVM instruction that failed? The processor instruction? The statement in which the method is caught (which is the only reasonable way)? Some random point up the call stack? Continuable exceptions are actually in use, but only in low-level code and very specific circumstances. For example, a page fault will trigger an exception handler, which then swaps in the page and retries the same processor instruction that failed.

Comment: @erikkallen: All very valid points, the bounds and behavior would have to be *very* clearly defined. I will point out that this is not a new thing, and it is implemented in some very high-level languages -- VB6, for instance (may it rest in peace -- **soon**) had `Resume` and the horror that was `Resume Next`. And most people got by perfectly well not actually knowing the details of how it worked. For any modern implementation going forward, I'd want the details. :-) (Writing that, I'm seeing a major distinction between my `retry` and VB6's `Resume`; but still, food for thought.)

Answer (score 14):

Checked Exceptions are just a small instance of a more general drive towards what Erik Meijer calls *type honesty*. I.e. procedures, methods, functions should not lie with their types. If you see a type signature, you should be able to trust its type.

This is not true for Java today (especially if you imagine a Java-- without Checked Exceptions).

If you have a type signature like this in Java:

```
Foo bar(Baz)
```

it says "I take a `Baz` as input and produce a `Foo` as output". But that's a lie.

Actually, `bar` takes *either* a `Baz` *or* `null` as input. It also takes the *entire* global state, class state and instance state as input, as well as the entire universe, really (via e.g. file I/O, network I/O, database I/O and so forth). And it does not produce a `Baz` as output either: it produces *either* a `Foo` *or* `null` *or* an Exception *or* `Bottom` (i.e. nothing at all). *Plus* its output also includes the entire global state, the entire class state, the entire instance state and really also the entire state of the universe.

`bar`'s *actual* type is:

```
(IO<Foo | null | Exception> | Bottom) bar(IO<Baz | null>)
```

or something like that.

This needs to be fixed, and Checked Exceptions are a (very small) part of that. I personally think that the other parts are more important and the Java designers should have concentrated on fixing *those* rather than exceptions (especially since exceptions are just side-effects, anyway and so you actually pretty much automatically fix exceptions for free when you fix side-effects).

Anyway, this is why I believe that the general idea *behind* Checked Exceptions is a Good Thing™, even if the specific implementation in Java might be a bit cumbersome.

How to fix Checked Exceptions depends a lot on what exactly you think is actually *wrong* with them.

Some people believe that the problem with Checked Exceptions is that when you change the internal implementation of your method to use a different helper method than it did before, which throws a different set of exceptions than the old one, you need to either explicitly handle those exceptions or declare them, thus breaking all your clients. Now, if that is what you think is wrong with Checked Exceptions, then there is only way to fix them: don't have them in the first place. Changing the exceptions you throw *is* a breaking change in your API contract, and breaking changes in your API contract *should* break client code. (Or more precisely: you shouldn't make breaking changes to your API contract, in order to *not* break client code.)

I believe that the main problem with Checked Exceptions as implemented by Java is that they break one of the main features of exceptions: non-local error handling. An error happens way over here, and is handled way over there, and these two are the only ones that need to know about it. If a different kind of error can happen over here, then the *only* place that needs to know about that new error and the only place that needs to *change* is the error handler over there.

With Checked Exceptions as implemented in Java, every piece of code in between *also* needs to change.

One proposal to fix this problem, are [Anchored Exception Declarations](http://WWW.CS.KULeuven.Be/publicaties/rapporten/cw/CW407.abs.html). (Improved in [Modular Anchored Exception Declarations](http://WWW.CS.KULeuven.Be/publicaties/rapporten/cw/CW544.abs.html).)

The idea of Anchored Exception Declarations is basically to use *delegation* for the exception declarations the same way that you use delegation in the method body, which is after all what creates the problem in the first place.

Say you have some file reader method which delegates to another method:

```
String fileReader(String filename) {
  return this.fileHelper.read(filename);
}
```

Now you go into the JavaDoc for `FileHelper#read` and cut&paste the exception list into your method:

```
String fileReader(String filename) throws IOException, CustomFileReaderEx
```

Now the author of `FileHelper#read` decides that he uses a different implementation strategy. Now he makes sure that the *actual* file read never can fail, by first ensuring that the file exists, can be opened, and is of the right format. So, naturally, the set of exceptions changes. It is no longer possible to get an `IOException` or a `CustomFileReaderEx`. Instead you can get a `InvalidFilenameEx` or `CorruptDataEx`. So, you cut&paste again:

```
String fileReader(String filename) throws InvalidFilenameEx, CorruptDataEx
```

Not only did *you* have to make that change, but everybody else who calls `fileReader` (and everybody who calls them and everybody who calls them and ...) as well. That's crazy! The reason why you delegated the call to the `fileHelper` in the first place was so that you need not concern yourself with those details.

So, the idea of Anchored Exception Declarations is to use this delegation for the Exception Declarations themselves. Instead of saying which *precise* exceptions you throw, you just blame someone else. "He did it!":

```
String fileReader(String filename) throws like this.fileHelper.read
```

And your clients just say:

```
Foo whatever() throws like fileReader
```

That way, when `FileHelper` changes its exceptions, then the *only* code that needs to change is the very top-level exception handling code, just like I described above for the *unchecked* case.

There are restrictions, of course. For example, in order to not break encapsulation, you can only use identifiers in your `throws like` clause which are accessible to all your clients. If, in this case, `fileHelper` is a `private` field, you cannot use it. You would need some other way. For example, if the `FileHelper` class is `public` (or if it is package private *and* all your clients live in the same package), you could instead say

```
String fileReader(String filename) throws like FileHelper.read
```

There are other restrictions listed in the paper as well. (One of those is lifted in the Modular Anchored Exception Declarations paper.)

Anyway, this is *one* way to ameliorate some of the problems with Checked Exceptions. However, Checked Exceptions have been around for almost 40 years now, and we still haven't figured them out, so it's *obviously* a hard problem.

Comment: The problem with exceptions as currently implemented in most languages is that they tightly couple the type of exception with the action to be taken, when the two things are largely orthogonal.  What I'd like to see would be an exception object with a virtual HasBeenSatisfied function; if an exception's HasBeenSatisfied property returns false at the end of a 'catch' block, the exception would propagate up the call stack.  Many types of exception would report HasBeenSatisfied as soon as they were caught.  For example, Dictionary.GetValue, when given a key that doesn't exist...

Comment: ...has to throw an exception because it can't otherwise satisfy its post-conditions (returning a value associated with a key).  Once the exception has propagated outside Dictionary.GetValue, however, the system is--as far as the Dictionary can tell--in a consistent state.  It's possible that the failure to get the value will mean the object containing the dictionary is in an inconsistent state, but if that object is in an inconsistent state, such inconsistency will be implied by the fact that TryGetValue failed, rather than the particular reason for the failure.

Comment: @supercat: Your example of `Dictionary.GetValue` isn't a very good example of exceptions, rather it's an example of very bad API design. It shouldn't throw an exception at all, it should return a `Maybe<TValue>`.

Comment: At least in .net, `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` supports a `TryGetValue` method.  If code is expecting that an entry may not exist, it should use that method.  On the other hand, if code is expecting that a value should exist and its absence would represent an unrecoverable problem, then having `GetValue` throw an exception is better than having a downstream `NullReferenceException` or other such problem.

Comment: @supercat You get both those behaviours with `Maybe<TValue>`. the first case you continue in an `ifPresent`, the second you call `orElseThrow`

Comment: @Caleth: If code is expecting that a value should exist, having an exception thrown by the attempt to retrieve the item would be better than having it thrown after the attempt reports failure.  Among other things, if code traps to a debugger at the "throw", information about the item being searched for will be available, even though such information wouldn't be available later.  BTW, I wonder if it would be helpful for an exception framework to allow exceptions to provide two messages, one of which might contain confidential data and should only be shown to trustworthy people, and...

Comment: ...the other of which could safely be logged and viewable by people who would not be trusted with confidential information.  In many cases, having a "record not found" exception report what was being searched for would be useful when troubleshooting, but such information should not be included in logs that may be viewable by people who shouldn't have access to confidential information.

Comment: @supercat You still have access to the same context: `value = dict.getValue(key).orElseThrow(() => new KeyNotFound(key))`. I'm not saying you can't also have `TValue getValueOrElseThrow(TKey)` if you like.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should read Neil Gafters [post regarding the improved exception handling](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-February/000003.html) in jdk7 and an [interview with Anders Hjelsberg](http://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html) about exception handling in C# (vs. Java)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should consider using a tri-state monad like Lift's Box type to handle Errors. Then you won't need to use Exceptions at all.

http://github.com/dpp/liftweb/blob/master/framework/lift-base/lift-common/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/common/Box.scala

Answer (score 0):

I don't see another way to bound a block of code possible of errors. I think that the try .. catch block is consistent. Ruby, as a improvement, has a keyword that allows to repeat the block of code that was fail, it's a good improvement, i think

Answer (score 0):

The exception-handling mechanism of [the programming language CLU](http://www.pmg.csail.mit.edu/CLU.html) is fully checked and is designed for rock-solid reliability.  Since almost all modern exception mechanisms are more permissive versions of CLU's original model, it is well worth careful study.  If you have access to a good library the [paper by Liskov and Snyder](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1313862) is well worth reading.

Regarding syntax, there is a [superb paper by Nick Benton and Andrew Kennedy](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/nick/except.ps) that explains the weaknesses of standard syntax and proposes a compelling new variation.  It should be required reading for anyone doing design in this area.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, checked exceptions might be a good thing, but a bigger issue is that most exception hierarchies are extremely broken.  The problem is that there's nothing inherent in an exception which indicates whether it indicates a problem beyond "the function call didn't work".  For example, if one calls a LoadDocument method and some type of exception gets thrown, there's no nice way of telling whether the correct thing to do is report that the file couldn't be loaded, but everything else is fine, or whether it would be better to shut down the program in an orderly fashion, or for that matter whether doing anything other than an abrupt quit would risk trashing the file system.  Checked exceptions could be nice if they carried an implication that the state of everything was just fine except to the extent implied by the fact that the method didn't work.  Unfortunately, no system I've seen has a useful hierarchy of exceptions to distinguish that.  Since exceptions are organized by what went wrong, rather than by the implications regarding system state, there's no good way to know what exceptions should be caught and wrapped, and what exceptions should bubble up.

Actually, what might be best in many cases would be a means of having multiple exceptions thrown at once, with a bundle of exceptions propagating up the stack until all have been caught.  I wonder if any system accommodate such a thing?